# How do I use the Multiselect input component with PostgreSQL? (Retool)

Tags: retool

I am trying to build my first app with Retool. I have a Multiselect input widget bound to a form data key in the internal PostgreSQL database. I am using this data field for a kind of tagging, where a person can have multiple attributes. When I run this app, I can select multiple attributes and they get stored into the database correctly as an array represented as a string (e.g., '["shiny", "fuzzy", "tall"]') but when I select a row in the table, the form does not get initialized from the data in the database.

I am wondering if I am missing something with the Multiselect widget or if I need to use something other than TEXT as the PostgreSQL data type (e.g., JSON or an array type).

Is there sample app which demonstrates this kind of use?